# Return different type upon class instantiation?

Tags: python, return, instantiation

So I am making my own version of a Complex class which works as a representation of imaginary numbers: Complex(a, b) where a + bi.

Thing is, I want to return something else based on arguments given. Im pretty sure I have to use the magic method **new** but I cant seem to be able to handle the arguments given. For instance:

```py
a = Complex(4, 5)
print(a)
> Complex(4, 5)
b = Complex(3, 0)
print(b)
> 3
c = Complex(0, 0)
print(c)
> 0
```

I want the b and c variables to be assigned numerical values. Not some sort of to-string solution where the class pretends to be something it is not. How can I do this?

Thanks for replies :))

Comment: "I cant seem to be able to handle the arguments given" What have you tried so far? What errors did you encounter? What exactly are you struggling with?

Comment: And what do you mean *exactly* by "pretends to be something"?

Comment: You want a factory function not a class constructor

Comment: Note that this *is* what one would use ``__new__`` for, but it is unclear what you are having problems with exactly.

Comment: Sorry i should elaborate. I thought it would be a good solution to, for example,  assign a variable an integer upon instantiating it with Complex(integer, 0), as this is equals to the integer itself. So a = Complex(3, 0) would assign a the value 3. Maybe its not so optimal? What do u guys think?

Comment: I also should say that i thought it would be a good solution as then it would be true that Complex(3, 0) == 3 as well as 3 == Complex(3, 0)

Comment: @Snusifer I mean, that can be the case regardless. Note, `3.0 == 3`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have pointed out in comments, this is exactly what `__new__` is for.

Here's what happens when you create an instance of a class `Complex`:

1. You write `Complex(a, b)`.
2. `Complex.__new__(a, b)` is called, and by default (that is, if you don't override the `__new__` method) this returns an empty object of type `Complex`.
3. If the object returned by `Complex.__new__(a, b)` (let's denote it as `cmplx`) is actually of type `Complex`, call `cmplx.__init__(a, b)`, or equivalently, `Complex.__init__(cmplx, a, b)`.

For your case, simply return an `int` in the `__new__` method when the second argument is called, and call the `__new__` method of the super class otherwise. That is:

```
class Complex:
    def __new__(cls, a, b):
        if b == 0:
            return a
        return super().__new__(cls)  # or equiv.: object.__new__(cls)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Not some sort of to-string solution where the class pretends to be
>   something it is not.

Isn't this exactly what you'd use `__str__` for, though? Maybe I'm not understanding you correctly, but if you're worried you wont be able to do math with your objects, you would just implement the relevant magic methods, such as `__add__`.

Comment: maybe you are right. Somehow i feel as though that particular solution isnt that, for a lack of a better word, "pure". Maybe im just obsessing

Comment: As far as I know that IS the canonical way to go about this. The `__str__` magic method returns a string that's meant to be helpful for the user - it isn't about the class "pretending" to be something that it's not. Hope that's helpful.

Comment: Or maybe not if i think about it. I want to do that Complex(3, 0) == 3. I could write eq to support this behaviour,, but i also want 3 == Complex(3, 0) to be true. Then again, could write the eq method, but then it becomes fairly complicated, which i believe isnt the most optimal solution. What do u think?

Comment: This article on making Complex numbers seems to cover a lot of the properties you want: http://hplgit.github.io/primer.html/doc/pub/class/._class-solarized005.html

Comment: I don't think you can dodge the fact that it will be complicated - or should I say complex?

Answer (score 0):

As said, `new` is a lot easier than other solutions because everything is fit up together. You could just say that if the second arg is zero then return `a` else call `__new__` again.

I this this might be exactly what you need because you pointed out that you struggled with finding a solution.